# Golang web app localization

Tags: http, go, localization, internationalization

I have a web app written in golang, and I am planning to make it available in more than one language, I've taken a look at multiple available l18n packages but some things were not clear to me.

What packages would be ideal to determine the users locale and load the site accordingly? Like from browser preferences or location?

Comment: Too broad, too many questions, some of which are highly opinion-based, some of which are seeking an off-site resource... this question should be closed for multiple reasons.

Comment: I agree, sorry for that, modified my question.

Comment: Question still asks for recommendations for an off site resource, still off topic for SO.

Comment: Start googling golang geo ip location - recommendations are not SO's thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n/

Then in your project you have to create a folder called i18n/ and use a function like this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n/i18n"
)

func loadI18nFiles() {
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("i18n")
    exists := false

    for _, file := range files {
        if err := i18n.LoadTranslationFile(fmt.Sprintf("i18n/%s", file.Name())); err != nil {
            log.Errorf("i18n: error loading file %s. err: %s", file.Name(), err)
        } else {
            log.Infof("i18n: lang file %s loaded", file.Name())
        }

        # Check if you have a default language
        if file.Name() == fmt.Sprintf("%s.json", "en-US") {
            exists = true
        }
    }

    if !exists {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Hey! You can't use a default language (%s) that doesn't exists on i18n folder", props.DefaultLang))
    }
}
```

Then to use, import the package and call the function:

```
T, _ := i18n.Tfunc("es-AR", "en-US")

fmt.Printf(T("key"))
```

Each file inside i18n folder is a .json

Example:

en-US.json

```
[
  {
    "id": "key",
    "translation": "Hello World"
  }
]
```

es-AR.json

```
[
  {
    "id": "key",
    "translation": "Hola Mundo"
  }
]
```